# Is it possible to use Linux USB drivers on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, usb, unix, driver

I have a USB device that I use on a daily basis and it has Linux and Windows drivers. I would like to use this device in Mac OS X (meaning not through a VM). Is it possible?

**edit**
System requirements from the read me:

- Linux 2.4 or 2.6
- System setup for kernel compilation.

Comment: What is the USB device that you wish to use?

Comment: Kvaser Leaf Light HS Controller Area Network (CAN) node.

Comment: Have you contacted the Kvaser company to request that they make a native Mac OS X driver available for their product? I think they would appreciate knowing that they have customers who require Mac OS X support for their product.

Comment: And I quote: 
We do not have any plans to create a Mac OS X driver for our products.  To my knowledge, we do not have any customers that have created their own Mac OS X drivers for our products.

I am aware that Parallels supports our Leaf unit in their VM.

Comment: Well, at least you asked! Kvaser may change their mind if enough customers request that they make it available. Otherwise, take their suggestion. Install Windows under Parallels on your Mac, and run Windows alongside Mac OS X for the functions where you require the Kvaser USB device.

Comment: This is currently what I have to do, it just irritates the crud out of me having to launch a VM just to test small bits of code / run acceptance tests for various projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because of completely different executable-architectures.

Only if you're willing to recompile them for OSX and they're Darwin based.

Comment: I'd be willing to recompile.  That is if it's possible (ie the drivers include source).  I just checked and the drivers contain source (headers, shell scripts, makefile etc...)